# Problems I'm having with glDrawRangeElements

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I'm having some problems with `glDrawRangeElements()`.  Basically I keep every mesh in a given model in the same vertex/index buffer, and use `glDrawRangeElements()` to draw them selectively (changing material and such between each draw, if I have to).

Here's the function I use to draw a mesh within a model:

```
void Mesh::drawMesh(uint index)
{
    if (index >= subMesh.size()) return;

    va.drawRange(subMesh[index].start, subMesh[index].end);
}
```

Where `va.drawRange()` is:

```
void VertexArray::drawRange(unsigned int start, unsigned int end)
{
    if (ready == false)
        return;

    /* Bind our vertex array */
    bindArray();

    /* Draw it's contents */
    if (ibo == 0)
        glDrawArrays(prim, start, (end - start) + 1);
    else
        glDrawRangeElements(prim, start, end, (end - start) + 1, iformat, NULL);

    unbindArray();
}
```

subMesh[i].start is the first index of the submesh.  subMesh[i].end is the last index.  These values are determined while the mesh is being imported (with assimp):

```
subMesh[i].start = (uint)indices.size();

for (uint j = 0; j < mesh->mNumFaces; ++j)
{
    aiFace& face = mesh->mFaces[j];
    indices.push_back(face.mIndices[0] + vertexOffset);
    indices.push_back(face.mIndices[1] + vertexOffset);
    indices.push_back(face.mIndices[2] + vertexOffset);
}

subMesh[i].end = (uint)indices.size() -1;

vertexOffset += mesh->mNumVertices;
```

This code is run for every mesh in the scene that assimp imports.

The problem I'm having is that drawMesh(0) and drawMesh(1) draws the same thing, even though subMesh[0] and subMesh[1] contain different values (specifically, subMesh[0] has start = 0 and end = 35, subMesh[1] has start = 36 and end = 71).  If I draw the entire mesh at once, using `glDrawElements()`, it draws both submeshes properly, so I know that the vertex and index data is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

(PS. I'm using OpenGL 3.3, core profile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using this function correctly:

```
glDrawRangeElements(prim, start, end, (end - start) + 1, iformat, NULL);
```

The second and third parameters of [`glDrawRangeElements()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glDrawRangeElements.xml) are **not** for specifing a sub-range of your index array. They are to tell the GL in advance which *vertex indices* you will use during that draw call, so they are specifying a sub-range in your *vertex arrays*. You should specify the part of your index array you want to render just via the `count` and `indices` parameters.

You can simply use

```
glDrawElements(prim, (end - start) + 1, iformat, (GLvoid*) (sizeof(yourElementType)*start) );
```

If you want to use `glDrawRangeElements()`, you should additionaly track what range of the vertex array each object uses.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly now!  Though, now I have to wonder, what's the point of glDrawRangeElements when I can do the same with glDrawElements?

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach: The point of `glDrawRangeElements()` is that it _might_ allow performance optimizations of the GL implementation. For example, the GL only has to ensure that the specified sub-range of the vertex data is updated/sent to the GPU before it can process the draw call. If you changed more data in that buffer, or only other regions, it does not have to wait for that. With glDrawElements(), _every_ byte of every VBO you use as a source for your attrib arrays might be relevant.

Comment: If I use `glDrawRangeElements(prim, start, end, (end - start) + 1, iformat, (void*)(indexSize(iformat)*start));`, am I still doing it wrong?

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach: yeah, that will still be wrong (in the general case, at least). You need something like `for (i=start; i<=end; i++) {a=min(a,indices[i]); b=max(b,indices[i]);}` and can then use `glDrawRangeElements(prim, a,b, ...)`.